# Generate HTML table from PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have the following PHP array queried from my mySQL Database in `$array`:

`Print_r` with pre tags gives me:

Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 2
)

This should be nicely formatted in a HTML table.

```
A 1
B 2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Please help us help you by providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Just because it's easy:

```
$array = array("A" => "1", "B" => "2");

echo "<table>";     
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

But you should try before you ask here, then, if you have a problem, you can ask about it.