# Display array values in a table?

Tags: php

I am working through understanding arrays and I am trying to figure out how I can display the keys and values of my_array in a table. I hope someone can show me how. This is the code I am using. When I do a  `var_dump($my_data);` I can see all the data, now I just want to understand how to display it. Thanks.

```
<?php

$result_list= array();
$query="SELECT * from tbl_uploads";

//Get info from table
$result=mysqli_query($db_con,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $result_list[] = $row;
}
foreach($result_list as $row) {

    $my_data[] = array(
        'user_id' => $row['user_id'],
        'user_name'  => $row['user_name'],
        'file'  => $row['file']
    );              
  }
var_dump($my_data);
?>
```

Comment: Here is the syntax: `foreach ($array as $key => $value) {}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate HTML table from PHP array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597068/generate-html-table-from-php-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple [example](https://eval.in/609663). First, take the array keys and use them as a heading:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach (array_keys(reset($my_data)) as $heading) : ?>
                <th><?php echo $heading ?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Next, loop the contents and display them in rows:

```
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($my_data as $row) : ?>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($row as $cell) : ?>
                    <td><?php echo $cell ?></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's great, very impressive. Thanks.